# Convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can somebody explain me one thing from the definition of convergent sequence?

On language of neighborhoods: the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ if and only if every neighborhood of $x$ contains $(x_n)$ $\textbf{for all but finitely many n}$. So I can't understand it, because I imagine it, like for some $N_1 \in \mathbb N$, if $n \geq N_1$ then for all $(x_n) \in V_{\delta}(x)$. So there are infinitely many $(x_n)$ in neighborhood.

What is wrong with my understanding? Thanks in advance

Comment: Nothing is wrong.

Comment: Your understanding and the definition do match. If you have a finite number of natural numbers, they have a biggest element, any number bigger is an element your looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding and definition of convergence is totally fine.

To see how it relates to the first definition, let $n_1,\cdots,n_m$ be the indices for which $x_n \not \in V_\delta(x)$. But then $x_n \in V_\delta(x)$ for each $n > n_m$, giving you a new candidate for your $N_1$.

And conversely, $0$ is certainly a finite number of exceptions to have, so equivalence is easy to see.